# og image not scraping for facebook share dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Here is my properties:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Hiring Senior Scientist, Enzymology" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://jobrangers.com/en/job/66734c1e/614d5b8a" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://jobrangers.com/images/jobrangersopengraph.jpg" />
```

Facebook suggests using a 1200x630 image, as described here: [click here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content)

We are using the share dialog.

I'm not quite sure why this image is not pulling but the remainder of content is.

**I've looked around Stack and have not found a good solution to this problem.**

Comment: It looks like you have got it sorted as it works OK for me when scraping.

Comment: @Malcolm Im not seeing the image when posting on facebook through the share dialog.

Comment: Does it work when using the following? https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://jobrangers.com/en/job/66734c1e/614d5b8a